# IE8 Script error (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

My slider (layerslider) isn't displaying in IE8-9, so I started to investigating and found this error in IE8 console -

```
Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js
```

Maybe this is why the slider isn't displaying in IE8-9? Could someone please help with this.

**The site is** - http://madisonandmonroe.com/

Comment: Can you add enough code to your question to reproduce the error?

Comment: @BSMP sorry, added the link just now